# Query a Nested Json in Mongodb and fetch all results

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a nested Json Document in the mongo db as shown below:
/* 1 */

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf159cc6bf6ab0ac374f80c"),
    "name" : "Jack",
    "age" : "30",
    "info" : {
        "0" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "luffy"
        },
        "1" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "sanji"
        },
        "2" : {
            "status" : "false",
            "name" : "zoro"
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf15f286bf6ab0ac374f8ed"),
    "name" : "Mack",
    "age" : "33",
    "info" : {
        "0" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "naruto"
        },
        "1" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "sakura"
        },
        "2" : {
            "status" : "false",
            "name" : "sasuke"
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I wanted to do is query and fetch those results where status = 'true'. After some googling I came to know how to query a nested document and came up with a sample query:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"info.0.status":"true"})
```

But as you know from the above query, the query will only fetch the appropriate results from the 0th array,How do I get the query to iterate through the arrays and return documents with "status":"true" .Also I am new to Mongodb, kindly ignore any mistakes.

Comment: Can you try: db.getCollection('test').find( { info: { status:true } } )

Comment: Tried the above query ,it dint return anything.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work - I was wrongly understood. But as suggested in answer, I feel the data modelling to be reconsidered as suggested in answer.

Comment: Used the above query too, but still fetched no records.

Answer (score 1):

If you query `db.getCollection('test').find({"info.0.status":"true"})` it will return as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf159cc6bf6ab0ac374f80c"),
    "name" : "Jack",
    "age" : "30",
    "info" : {
        "0" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "luffy"
        },
        "1" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "sanji"
        },
        "2" : {
            "status" : "false",
            "name" : "zoro"
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf15f286bf6ab0ac374f8ed"),
    "name" : "Mack",
    "age" : "33",
    "info" : {
        "0" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "naruto"
        },
        "1" : {
            "status" : "true",
            "name" : "sakura"
        },
        "2" : {
            "status" : "false",
            "name" : "sasuke"
        }
    }
}
```

However, as described in requirement, you need to model your data as:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf159cc6bf6ab0ac374f80c"),
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": "30",
    "info": [
      {
        "status": "true",
        "name": "luffy"
      },
      {
        "status": "true",
        "name": "sanji"
      },
      {
        "status": "false",
        "name": "zoro"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf15f286bf6ab0ac374f8ed"),
    "name": "Mack",
    "age": "33",
    "info": [
      {
        "status": "true",
        "name": "naruto"
      },
      {
        "status": "true",
        "name": "sakura"
      },
      {
        "status": "false",
        "name": "sasuke"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), it returns the expected result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$info",
          as: "info",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$info.status",
              "true"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Sample response:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf159cc6bf6ab0ac374f80c"),
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "luffy",
        "status": "true"
      },
      {
        "name": "sanji",
        "status": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf15f286bf6ab0ac374f8ed"),
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "naruto",
        "status": "true"
      },
      {
        "name": "sakura",
        "status": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes,but before using the $filter operator i need to change the structure right, how do I change the structure of my data as shown above?

Comment: @AustinJoy, with the existing data model, the query `{"info.0.status":"true" }` will rturn the entire document since one of the nested objects satisfied the query. If you need to return only part of the nested document, suggested data model is one of the solutions.

Comment: yes I understood that, although my data is already inserted in the above form, is it possible to query it in a way so that I can remodel the data first.